# About the LazyColumn of Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to do a simple chat interface which has one message list(LazyColumn) and a TextField.

I have done them sparately.Now I want to combinate them,but I have some problems.

Firstly, I don't know how to make the TextField in the bottom of parent.And I found if I put them in a Column, the LazyColumn will cover the TextField if there are too many messages.

Thank you if you help me to save these problems.

this is my code.

```
@Composable
fun inputBox(value: String, onValueChange: (String)->Unit, modifier: Modifier){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = value,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            placeholder = {
                Text(text = "Send a chat")
            },
            shape = CircleShape,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(10.dp),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            )
        )
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun chatList(messageList: MutableList<ChatMessage>, modifier: Modifier){
    LazyColumn{
        items(messageList){
            DialogBox(text = it.text, type = it.type)
        }
    }
}
```

When I use View to draw interfacial design, the RecyclerView will set its height automatically.But the Column won't.I don't know how to deal with.

I am not native English speaker,hope you can understand my question.

Comment: You can either use constraint layout or Column for this purpose. Using Column you can set weight for LazyColumn to 1 and input field height to wrap.

Comment: Thank you.It works.At first,I try to combine the list and inputText like: Column{LazyColumn, Column{inputText}}, I don't know why the LazyColumn will cover all of the screen so that I can't see my inputText.When I try 'Column{LazyColumn, inputText}',it can work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @leiteorz You can wrap your LazyColumn and TextFiled inside The Column. .weight(1f) modifier will occupy as much space it required.

```
@Composable
fun chatList(messageList: MutableList<ChatMessage>, modifier: Modifier){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(1f)){
            items(messageList){
                DialogBox(text = it.text, type = it.type)
            }
        }
        TextField(
            value = value,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            placeholder = {
                Text(text = "Send a chat")
            },
            shape = CircleShape,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(10.dp),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u.I don’t know when i need to draw component separately and when should write them in a column or row.

Answer (score 0):

I use "modifier.weight()" to save this problem.It works perfectly.If anyone has other method,please share with me